# Maven: Change the "test" phase directory from local .m2 to target?

Tags: maven, target

Forgive me if this is remedial, but I am still new to Maven and it's functionality.

In my project, when it "builds" and gets to the compile phase, it will create a target directory with just compiled libraries and update (or create if not there) the local .m2 directory.

When I get to the "test" phase, I want it to build against the target directory's library files, and not the local .m2 directory.

Any hints, recommendations, or suggests would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven has this concept of “the reactor”, which is just a fancy term for the list of projects being built. At the start of a Maven build, and at the end, Maven prints out this list of projects (using `/project/name` if defined or `groupId:artifactId` otherwise).

For each project in the reactor, Maven maintains a list of artifacts that have been attached. By default, each module's `pom.xml` is attached, and as each plugin runs, they have the option of attaching additional artifacts. Most plugins do not attach artifacts, here are some plugins that do:

- `jar:jar` creates a `.jar` and attaches it
- `war:war` creates a `.war` and attaches it
- `source:jar` creates a `.jar` of the source Java code and attaches it with a classifier of `source`
- `java doc:jar` creates a `.jar` of the JavaDocs ad attaches it with a classifier of `javadoc`

There is also a default primary artifact (this is the one that gets replaced by `jar:jar`) which is actually a directory and not a file, as such it will not get installed or deployed to the local repository cache or a remote repository.

So when in the reactor, and a plugin that attaches the primary artifact has not run yet, and another plugin asks for the primary artifact, it will be given the directory `${project.build.outputDirectory}`. If after the primary artifact as been attached, then that primary artifact will be provided.

The `test` phase happens before the `package` phase, so will use the directory and not the `.jar`. The `integation-test` phase happens after, so will always use the `.jar`.

Things get more complex in a multi-module project (which is where my long intro should help you out)

Maven has to build the test classpath. If one of the dependencies is within the reactor, Maven will use the artifact attached to the reactor. Otherwise it will use the local cache (populating from the remote repositories if necessary).

When you run

```
mvn test
```

In a multimdule project from the root, there is no replacement of the default (directory-based) artifact, so intra-module classpath will be to the `target/classes` directories.

When you run

```
mvn package
```

In the same project, however, because each module completes its life cycle sequentially, all the dependent modules will have swapped in their `.jar` files as their attached artifact.

All of this should show you that Maven is doing the sensible thing. Hope this has helped.

Comment: When you talk about the "projects" in the "reactor", is that the same thing as the modules?

Comment: Mostly, though with Maven 3's `-pl`, `-am` and `-amd` options it need not be the full set, but instead only a subset of the tree of modules.

Answer (score 3):

The `test` phase is going to execute tests on your project.  The project won't reference itself via the dependency mechanism.  Only dependencies will be referenced via your local repository, i.e. `.m2/repository`

Also, it's not the `compile` phase that installs the artifact to the local repository, it's the `install` phase.  And, then, there's a later phase, called `deploy`, that will deploy the artifact to a remote repository, provided you have a remote repository configured as the deploy target.  Note, install and deploy are nearly identical phases except install is a local only thing; thus, it's the common build phase to hit when doing dev environment work.  Normally the build server will do the deploy stuff.